# An embedded Youtube video won't fullscreen

Tags: javascript, youtube, embed

I have embedded a youtube video into a website via a drupal module (I'm not sure if that's relevant here). Everything works fine and I'm able to interact with the video via javascript and do everything I need, however, fullscreen no longer works.

Here is the string I'm using to embed the video:

```
orientation.start_id = $('#orientation-player').attr('data-youtube_id');
var params = {allowScriptAccess: 'always'};
var atts = {id: 'orientation-player', wmode: 'opaque'};
swfobject.embedSWF('http://www.youtube.com/v/'+orientation.start_id+'?version=3&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=orientation-player',
    'orientation-player', '854', '480', '8', null, null, params, atts);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try changing line 2 to,

```
var params = {allowScriptAccess: 'always', allowfullscreen: 'true'};
```